# Stuck at "Send an Ad request" on Facebook Audience Network (FAN) integration in my iOS app

Tags: ios, mobile-application, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to integrate Facebook Audience Network (FAN) for the first time in my app. I have created a Native Ad Placement in my Property "Wall App".

I have integrated FAN SDK into my iOS app and also receiving test ads in both simulator and physical devices. My app is not on the apple app store yet. It is under development.

Regarding FAN setup process, I think I am still stuck at "Send an ad request" step. It is mentioned in the guides that when first ad request is sent, I will receive an email from FAN team. But I have received no email yet. And I am already seeing test ads. What am I missing? How do I proceed for placement review or app review and making my app live on the store with FAN integration? Please help!

Screenshot showing how I am stuck at the step number 2 with FAN integration

[image]

I also read similar question-answer threads on FAN community help, and I see I need to send an ad request from a device on which admin is logged into the FB app on the device. I did that too. I don't understand if this need to be done after I make my iOS app live on the apple app store. If you are aware of the process, please throw some light on it. And if it is so that I need to make the app live first and then FAN integration is reviewed and approved, won't that be the wrong sequence of steps than what should be ideally? Please help!

Comment: Hey I'm, having the same problem any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Hold onto your hat because this is ridiculous, but here's what finally worked for me:

I turned off test mode, then made a call from local dev to clear test devices. (Objective-C here):

```
[FBAdSettings clearTestDevices];
```

Once this was done, logged into FB add on an actual device using a FB account with an email that's registered to my business account.

Tried for days until this is finally what worked! Now if I could only get FB ads showing in Simulator instead of constant no-fill, it would be a miracle.